# Dependency injection and InternalsVisibleTo attribute

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, architecture, internalsvisibleto

In my solution I have an IoC container (Ninject) in its own module. It works fine to resolve dependencies between public classes of all modules, but how could it resolve dependencies of internal classes?

I have a public class called `Customer`, in the BusinessRules project. Before saving a new customer, many validation methods must be called, and they're all in an internal class called `CustomerValidator`. This validator class is an implementation detail and should be called only to validate a new customer, so no other project should see it.

The problem is that the IoC Container can't see the `CustomerValidator` (since it's internal), and it can't resolve a dependency like this:

```cs
public class Customer(ICustomerValidator customerValidator)
{
//...
}
```

The IoC container can see only the public `Customer` class, but knows nothing about the existence of the internal `CustomerValidator` class. One possible solution is to use the InternalsVisibleTo attribute, commonly used for unit tests, and then the IoC would be able to see my internal classes:

```cs
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MySolution.IoC")]
```

Is that an acceptable solution? Are there any other ways of doing it while keeping the CustomerValidator internal?

Comment: What is the value of keeping it internal?  Encapsulation is good, but also has its limits.

Comment: Your a little unclear about where the consuming class is with respect to the validator. Same project?

Comment: @HenkHolterman The idea of keeping the validator class internal  is to hide an implementation detail.

Comment: @HenkHolterman The Customer (public) and the CustomerValidator (internal) classes are in the same project. The IoC is in another project, and can see only the Customer class.

Comment: Strongly related: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/222707/27316

Comment: And there are links to other Q+A there. The consensus is to make the Validator public. Which sounds OK to me. Otherwise: forget about DI. DI doesn't (can't) do implementation details.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thank you, Henk. In this link I found two mentions to the InternalsVisibleTo attribute, and apparently nobody thinks it's a bad idea to use it. What do you think about using this attribute? Do you think it creates a hidden dependency between modules?

Comment: Yes, it is a hack.  Not just hidden, it is also circular.  OK for unit testing, but lying to yourself otherwise. Just make the validators public.